# How to add extra fields to strapi upload plugin?

Tags: plugins, strapi

I am trying to build a multilingual api with language code (e.g title_en) at the end of each text field.
In Strapi upload plugin assets have caption field. How can I customize the model to have multiple captions for each language ? For instance, caption_en, caption_az, caption_ru etc.

Comment: did you find a solution for it?

Comment: unfortunately not.